# How can I create a Crypt::RSA object from modulus, exponent, and private exponent?

Tags: php, perl, rsa

I'm trying to port the following php functionality over to perl:

```
public function loadKey($mod, $exp, $type = 'public')
{
    $rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
    $rsa->signatureMode = CRYPT_RSA_SIGNATURE_PKCS1;
    $rsa->setHash('sha256');
    $rsa->modulus = new Math_BigInteger(Magicsig::base64_url_decode($mod), 256);
    $rsa->k = strlen($rsa->modulus->toBytes());
    $rsa->exponent = new Math_BigInteger(Magicsig::base64_url_decode($exp), 256);

    // snip...
}
```

I need to convert a string in the form ("RSA.$mod.$exp.$private_exp"):

```
RSA.mVgY8RN6URBTstndvmUUPb4UZTdwvwmddSKE5z_jvKUEK6yk1u3rrC9yN8k6FilGj9K0eeUPe2hf4Pj-5CmHww==.AQAB.Lgy_yL3hsLBngkFdDw1Jy9TmSRMiH6yihYetQ8jy-jZXdsZXd8V5ub3kuBHHk4M39i3TduIkcrjcsiWQb77D8Q==
```

...to a Crypt::RSA object. I've split out the components so I have $mod, $exp, and $private_exp, but the perl Crypt::RSA API doesn't seem to have a way to explicitly set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Worked out on IRC, documenting it here for the rest of the world: it's completely undocumented but `Crypt::RSA::Key` *does* have methods called `n`, `e`, and `d` that correspond to the modulus, the public exponent, and the private exponent. Modulo bugs in the check function (which is *supposed* to work if `p` and `q` are unavailable but `n` is, but actually doesn't), it's possible to create a working key with those methods.

We solved the problem together by creating a subclass of `Crypt::RSA::Key::Private` with a factory method that decodes the base64 encoding (using [MIME::Base64::URLSafe](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/MIME::Base64::URLSafe)) and the additional binary encoding (using [Math::BigInt](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Math::BigInt)->from_hex and `unpack "H*"`) and then sets those three private members, and the `Crypt::RSA` modules were able to accept it as a Key.